# Javascript InnerHtml not working with razor devexpress

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, devexpress

i want to show a combobox from devexpress using innerHtml. but is not working. please help me. thanks...

and this is my javascript :

```
 var divContent = document.createElement("div");
 var devexCombo = '@@Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(settings => { settings.Name = "DepartmentId"; settings.Width = 300; settings.SelectedIndex = 0;' +
                     ' settings.Properties.DropDownStyle = DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.DropDownStyle.DropDownList;' + 
                     ' settings.Properties.IncrementalFilteringMode = DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.IncrementalFilteringMode.StartsWith;' + 
                     ' settings.Properties.TextField = "Text"; settings.Properties.ValueField = "Id"; settings.Properties.ValueType = typeof(int);' + 
                     ' settings.Properties.DropDownRows = 10; }).BindList(ViewBag.DepartmentList).Bind(Model.DepartmentId).GetHtml()';
 divContent.innerHTML = devexCombo;
```

Comment: innerHTML is html content like '<div>blavbla..."

Comment: and then, how to display devexpress combobox inside a div ? Thanks

Comment: mmm parsint it to hatml string and then use innerHTML

Comment: sorry, what do you mean? i don't know. maybe you can write for sample